# backbone.js view event does not execute

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I have the following backbone.js view shown below. It was working fine, and now the click event does not execute when the form button is clicked. No errors in console, or any other obvious signs of why is shown.

```
window.FormOptionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#test-option').html()),
    render: function (eventName) {
        $('#test1').append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
         $('#test2').append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});


window.AddTestView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template($('#test-add').html()),

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.render();

    },

    events: {
             "click button": "addTest" 
    },

    addTest: function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var test = new Test({
            test1: {
                firstName: $("#test1 option:selected").val(),
                lastName: $("#test1Score").val()
            },
            test2: {
                firstName: $("#test2 option:selected").val(),
                lastName: $("#test2Score").val()
            }
        });

        test.add(result);
        app.navigate("tests", true);

    },

    render: function (eventName) {
        $('#content').html(this.template());
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (test) {
             this.renderSelectBox(test);
        }, this);
        return this;
    },

    renderSelectBox: function (item) {
       var optionView = new FormOptionView({
           model: item
       });
       $(this.el).append(optionView.render().el);
    }
});
```

The corrosponding HTML

```
        <script type="text/template" id="test-option">
        <option><%= firstName %> <%= lastName %></option>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="test-add">

                <form id="addTest" action="#">
                        <label for="test1">Test1:</label>

                        <select id="test1">
                            <option></option>
                        </select>

                        <label for="test1Score">Score:</label>

                        <input id="test1Score" type="number" />



                        <label for="test2">Test 2:</label>

                        <select id="test2">
                            <option></option>
                        </select>

                        <label for="test2Score">Score:</label>

                        <input id="test2Score" type="number" />


                        <button id="add">Add</button>
                    </form>

           </script>
```

Comment: Can we see the corresponding HTML for this?

Comment: Try specifying the id of the button - "click .add": "addTest".  There does at least seem to be a button inside of your root element.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the corresponding HTML, my best guess is that your `<button>` is outside the scope of your view.  Click events are only attached to children of the root element of your View.

Comment: Just found the views el tag corresponded to a bunch of empty <divs>. Not to sure why but a simple el: $('#content') managed to fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just found the views `el` tag corresponded to a bunch of empty `<div>`s. Not to sure why but a simple `el: $('#content')` managed to fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, as you've already discovered, is that your view wasn't handling its `el` properly.

When your view is rendered, Backbone hooks up the events by using jQuery's [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on the view's `this.el`.

If you don't explicitly set the `el` (through the constructor as `new V({ el: ... })`, in the view's definition as `el: ...`, or by calling [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement)), then the `el` will be constructed using various view properties [as noted in the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el); the default `el` is just a simple `<div>`. This is where your empty `<div>`s are coming from.

You were doing this:

```
render: function (eventName) {
    $('#content').html(this.template());
    _.each(this.collection.models, function (test) {
         this.renderSelectBox(test);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

and somewhere else you were probably doing a simple `add_test_view.render()`. The result is that the event `delegate` is bound to the view's `el` (an empty `<div>`) and that `el` is never added to the DOM; if you have `delegate` bound to something that isn't in the DOM then you never get any events.

If you say `el: '#content'` in your view definition, then Backbone will use `#content` as your `el` and your view would look more like this:

```
el: '#content',
//...
render: function (eventName) {
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    this.collection.each(function(test) {
        this.renderSelectBox(test);
    }, this);
    return this;
},
renderSelectBox: function (item) {
    var optionView = new FormOptionView({
        model: item
    });
    this.$el.append(optionView.render().el);
}
```

Notice that I switch to `this.collection.each`, Backbone collections have [various Underscore methods mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you don't have to access `collection.models` manually; I've also switched to [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) since view already have a cached jQuery'd version of `this.el`.